# How do I achieve ModelBinding with Html.RenderAction?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, modelbinders, renderaction

I'm working through a MVC book which uses the older version of `Html.RenderAction`. So it looks like this in the book `Html.RenderAction("Summary", "Cart");` I have had to convert to `Html.RenderAction<CartController>(m => m.Summary(new Cart()));`.

Where Summary looks like:

```
public ViewResult Summary(Cart cart)
{
    return View(cart);
}
```

I have a binding set up for Cart in the global.asax

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBinder());
```

So what is the best way do get the Binding to create the parameter `cart` instance rather then me manually doing it?

I have several ideas of how to fix this, but since I'm new to MVC I'm looking to see what the accepted practice is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
HTML.RenderAction()
```

use

```
HTML.RenderPartial()
```

for eg:-

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Summary", new cart(parameters)); %>
```

this will work sure.

Comment: you can refer here for futher reference

http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/